# SQL Query throws error "failed to convert parameter value from a Guid to String'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to get the UserName and put it in `TempData` but I get an error when the code reaches the `ExecuteReader()` method.

Here's my query code:

```
var InvoiceId = TempData["newinvoice"];
TempData["invoiceid"] = InvoiceId;
var UserID = TempData["UserID"];

string connection = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=project;Integrated Security=true;";

using (SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(connection))
{
    using (SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand("SELECT UserName FROM AspNetUsers WHERE Id = @id"))
    {
        sqlcomm.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = UserID;

        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
        {
            sqlcomm.Connection = sqlconn;
            sqlconn.Open();

            sda.SelectCommand = sqlcomm;

            SqlDataReader sdr = sqlcomm.ExecuteReader();

            while (sdr.Read())
            {
                TempData["UserId"] = sdr["UserName"];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The User Id from `TempData["UserID"]` is an `nvarchar(450)` not an integer. I have no clue why that exception is happening - any help?

Note: here's an example from one of my user ids:

```
'aa776084-053e-452c-8b0d-b445cdbf457d'
```

Comment: What is the type of `Id` in database?

Comment: @GuruStron nvarchar(450)

Comment: I suggest using types instead of `var` in all of your declarations. It would make the code a bit easier to read and debug, and it might even show you where you error is before it goes to query the database.

Comment: Try `sqlcomm.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ((Guid)UserID).ToString("D");`

Comment: @Origin `TempData[string]` returns an `object` so changing `var` to `object`  will not help in this case.

Comment: If it's really an nvarchar (the column that is, `TempData` can't be nvarchar since it's not a database) then why are you passing a parameter of type `VarChar` and not `NVarChar`? It's highly likely it should be `SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier`. What is `UserId.GetType().Name`? If that prints System.Guid then change it to `SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = UserID.ToString()`. Also what's up with the `SqlDataAdapter`? It's pointless here

Comment: That said, if the type of UserId is System.Guid and your database field is *really* UniqueIdentifier then you should use `SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = UserID`. If the field is UniqueIdentifier and UserId is a string then use `SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = Guid.Parse(UserID)`. It all depends on the actual types of things. Your statement that TempData is nvarchar is positively false and since we don't know the type of UserId it's hard to guess. But those are all the possible combinations so I'd suggest trying them all until one works. If Guid.Parse throws then you have a bad string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your id is a [uniqueidentifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/uniqueidentifier-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and if so I would recommend changing your database and code to use GUIDs.

However to fix your problem, you should be able to pass in the UserId and call toString() (as the value is most likely an object) e.g:

```
sqlcomm.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.NVarChar, UserID.ToString());
```

If you're only going to return one results, maybe use [ExecuteScalar()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1)

```
    using (SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(connection))
    {
        using (SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 1 UserName from AspNetUsers where Id=@id", sqlconn)
        {
            sqlcomm.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.NVarChar, UserID.ToString());
            object result = sqlcomm.ExecuteScalar();
            if (result != null)
            {
                TempData["UserId"] = result.ToString(); // It looks like you're mixing UserId & UserName .
            }
        }
    }
```